# Question about ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a sql sentence like this:

```
INSERT INTO products (ProductSKU,ProductPrice,ProductCheckDate) 
VALUES ('0000001','22,00','2019-01-01 00:00:00') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    ProductLastPrice = ProductPrice, 
    ProductPrice = '22,00', 
    ProductLastCheckDate = ProductCheckDate,
    ProductCheckDate = '2019-01-01 00:00:00';
```

I need to store old values when registry its updated but sometimes, the ProductLastCheckDate its the same as ProductCheckDate

Im doing something wrong?

Comment: What is the PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY that will trigger the duplicate-key behavior? I don't assume either ProductPrice or ProductCheckDate or their combination is a UNIQUE KEY.

Comment: My fault, i update the query. ProductSku its the unique key